# How to use correctly requestAnimationFrame function in tetris games?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to write tetris game using javascript, but a few days ago I am stuck on trying to animate created piece of block. My code looks like that:

**Draw.js**

```
export default class Draw {
    constructor() {
        this._canvas = document.getElementById(`main_screen`);
        this._context = this._canvas.getContext(`2d`);
    }

    get canvas() {
        return this._canvas;
    }

    get context() {
        return this._context;
    }

    get clearAll() {
        return this._clearAll();
    }

    get save() {
        return this._save();
    }

    _clearAll() {
        this._context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }

    _save() {
        this._context.save();
    }
}
```

**BlockController.js**

```
import Draw from './Draw.js';
import Generator from './Generator.js';

export default class BlockController extends Draw {
    constructor(x, y, width, height) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.blockStartPoint = 160;
    }

    get drawBlock() {
        return this._drawBlock();
    }

    /**
     * Function creates and draws block.
     */
    async _drawBlock() {
        this.x = this.blockStartPoint;
        const block = await Generator.getBlock();
        const blockColor = await Generator.getBlockColor();

        block.forEach(row => {
            row.forEach(column => {
                if(column === 1) {
                    this.context.fillStyle = `#${blockColor}`;
                    this.context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                    this.context.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                }
                this.x += this.width;
            });
            this.x = this.blockStartPoint;
            this.y += this.height;
        });
    }

    moveBlock() {
        this.y += this.height;
    }
}
```

**BoardController.js**

```
import Draw from './Draw.js';

export default class BoardController extends Draw {
    constructor(x, y, width, height) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.blocksAmountInRow = this.canvas.width / width;
        this.blockAmountInColumn = this.canvas.height / height;
    }

    get drawBoard() {
        return this._drawBoard();
    }

    /**
     * Function creates and draws game board.
     */
    _drawBoard() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.blocksAmountInRow; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < this.blockAmountInColumn; j++) {
                this.context.fillStyle = `#E6F1FF`;
                this.context.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                this.context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                this.y += this.height;
            }
            this.x += this.width;
            this.y = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**GameController.js**

```
import BlockController from './BlockController.js';
import BoardController from './BoardController.js';

export default class GameController {
    constructor() {
        this.boardController = new BoardController(0, 0, 20, 20);
        this.blockController = new BlockController(0, 0, 20, 20);
    }

    update() {
        this.boardController.clearAll;
        this.boardController.drawBoard;
        this.blockController.drawBlock;
        this.blockController.moveBlock();
    }

    init() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Anyone has an any idea how to force block to animate? I know that my update function creates new block and board over and over, but I don not have any idea how to handle with that. Thanks for help!

Comment: when `GameController.init()` is called, are any errors thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @kshetline:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.update());
```

seams to be the problem. The fix might look like this:

```
init () {

  const that = this;
  let last = -Infinity;

  (function loop () {
    const 
      now = new Date().getTime(),
      delta = now - last
    ;

    if (delta > 500) {  // delta is just some delay
      that.update();
      last = now;
    }

    that.frameID = window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  })()
}
```

using the return value of `window.requestAnimationFrame` can come in handy, if you want to stop the loop wih `window.cancelAnimationFrame`.

`window.requestAnimationFrame` asks the browser to trigger the given callback once, so the get a real "loop", you need to do that over and over again. Using `setTimeout` to run `window.requestAnimationFrame` is not needed. Without delay `window.requestAnimationFrame` can run up sixty times per second, but slowes down if the browser cannot manage to compute and render that fast. So it might be a good idea to capture the time step, if needed.

Comment: Would be good to show how to use `delta` from here. Also, it's not *up to sixty  times per seconds*, but up to the monitor's refresh rate. At least Chrome aligns animation frames to the monitor's refresh rate.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't studied your code to know if there might be other problems, but you've definitely got a problem here:

```
    update() {
        this.boardController.clearAll;
        this.boardController.drawBoard;
        this.blockController.drawBlock;
        this.blockController.moveBlock();
    }

    init() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this));
    }
```

As written, you'll get one and only one update, ever. `requestAnimationFrame` only requests a *single* event, not a series of events.

Other possible issues with your code aside, one step forward would be something like this:

```
    update() {
        this.boardController.clearAll;
        this.boardController.drawBoard;
        this.blockController.drawBlock;
        this.blockController.moveBlock();
        // You might want to make the line below conditional, so that
        // some flag that indicates the game is over prevents another
        // request from being made here.
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.update());
        }, 100); // <- Use whatever refresh rate, in milliseconds, works best here.
    }

    init() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.update());
    }
```

Comment: Another important aspect is timing. OPs code doesn't depend on time, but instead just increments `y` position by a fixed step on every update. So with your suggestion the animation speed will depend on the screen refresh rate. Blocks will fall so fast, that one can't even react. ;-)

Comment: True, @zett42, I'll add a delay.

Answer (score 0):

It almost works, but there is another problem. On the beginning the board and block is drawn like this:
[image: first step]

and then drawn only new random block without board:

[image: second step]

The question is how to every time draw board and this same block as on the beginning?

From the other hand can you say something about the quality of my code? This is my first project in javascript and I wonder if I'm going in the right direction.